# How to check for nested property in BsonDocument - Contains doesn't work

Tags: c#, mongodb, bsondocument

When I wrote code to grab a nested property, it fails when the entire path doesn't exist - which is fair enough
`bsonDoc["Meeting"]["Session"]["Time"]`

I can't see any way to protect against this, writing
`bsonDoc.Contains("Meeting.Session.Time")` returns `false` even when it exists

Writing `bsonDoc.Contains("Time")` also returns fails, even when it does exist, so it can't even check the field property at all, if it's nested... ?

The documentation and even the code contains no clue how to do what I need. Not sure it's possible.

Is there a way to write a guard clause for nested bson document properties - ie does the BsonDocument class have a nested key checking mechanism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any method from `BsonDocument` that supports getting element/value with the nested property.

But you can implement the logic/extension method to deal with:

Concept:

1. Split key by '.'.
2. First-level search.

   2.1 First `chainKey` will search from `BsonDocument` via `TryGetValue`.

   2.2 If the key has existed, `@value` (`BsonValue`) will contain value (This is needed while querying for nested levels).

   2.3 If the key doesn't exist, break the loop logic.
3. Second-level or further level search

   3.1 Concept is the same with *2*, just will search from `BsonValue` (as stated in *2.2*).

```cs
public static class BsonDocumentExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetChainedValue(this BsonDocument doc, string key, out BsonValue @value)
    {
        @value = default;
        // Get key, value from passed BsonDocument for first time, then refer to BsonValue to get key, value for nested property
        bool first = true;
        
        try
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
                return false;
        
            string[] chainedKeys = key.Split(".").ToArray();
            
            bool hasKey = false;
            foreach (var chainKey in chainedKeys)
            {       
                if (first)
                {
                    hasKey = doc.TryGetValue(chainKey, out @value);
                    
                    first = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    hasKey = (@value.ToBsonDocument()).TryGetValue(chainKey, out @value);
                }

                // Throw exception if key not existed.
                if (!hasKey)
                    throw new Exception();
            }
        
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {           
            @value = default;
            return false;   
        }
    }
}
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7BLFUG)

---

The concept above is same as multiple if logic as below:

```cs
if (doc.TryGetValue("Meeting", out BsonValue meetingValue))
{
    if ((meetingValue.ToBsonDocument()).TryGetValue("Session", out BsonValue sessionValue))
    {
        if ((sessionValue.ToBsonDocument()).TryGetValue("Time", out BsonValue timeValue))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(timeValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. In the end, I needed to set the chained value, so I modiified your extension to be a `NestedValueExists()` method and used it to guard the setter

Answer (score 0):

I using the same concept, but a little different aproach.

1. This code return the value it self, not if is cheked;
2. This code don't verify for the first interation;

```
public static class BsonDocumentExtensions
{
    public static BsonValue GetNestedValue(this BsonDocument doc, string key)
    {
        try
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
                return false;
        
            string[] chainedKeys = key.Split(".").ToArray();
            BsonValue result = doc.GetValue(chainedKeys[0]);
            var regexIndex = new Regex(@"\d+");
            
            for (int i = 1; i < chainedKeys.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (regexIndex.IsMatch(chainedKeys[i]))
                {
                    int index = regexIndex.Match(chainedKeys[i]).Value.ToIns32();
                    result = result[index].ToBsonDocument();
                    continue;
                }

                result = (result.ToBsonDocument()).GetValue(chainedKeys[i]);
            }
        
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {           
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call this extension like this

> bsonDoc.GetNestedValue("Meeting.Session.Time")

If you know you have lists (arrays) in BsonDocument, than you should do like bellow

> bsonDoc.GetNestedValue("Meeting.[0].Session.Time")
> bsonDoc.GetNestedValue("Meeting.Session.[3].Time")